# mysql explain taking time

Tags: mysql

I am doing an explain plan on following select query and the explain plan never returns. The explain plan was returning in 2-3 minutes before but now it's taking for ever and never returns. Following is the explain query i am running

```
explain SELECT * FROM
((
SELECT DISTINCT hi.target_profile_id, hi.handset_id
FROM handset_inclusions hi,
campaigns c,
campaigns_target_profiles ctp
WHERE hi.target_profile_id = ctp.target_profile_id
AND c.id=ctp.campaign_id
AND c.active=1
AND c.house_ad = true
ORDER BY target_profile_id, handset_id)
UNION DISTINCT
(
SELECT DISTINCT hi.target_profile_id, hi.handset_id
FROM handset_inclusions hi,
campaigns c,
campaign_flights f,
campaigns_target_profiles ctp
WHERE hi.target_profile_id = ctp.target_profile_id
AND c.id=ctp.campaign_id
AND c.active=1
AND c.house_ad = false
AND c.id = f.campaign_id
AND (f.active_flight = true or c.id in (199,857,947)
       OR (NOW() >= DATE_SUB(f.start_time, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
           AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(f.end_time, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)))
ORDER BY target_profile_id, handset_id)
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT prof.target_profile_id, h.id as handset_id
FROM  (SELECT distinct (pc.target_profile_id) as target_profile_id
       FROM placements p, sites s, publishers pubs, placement_3PNchannel pc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 3PNchannel c
       ON c.id = pc.3PNchannel_id
       WHERE p.id = pc.placement_id
         AND p.siteid = s.id
         AND pubs.id = s.publisherid
         AND pc.active = TRUE
         AND pubs.allows_3pn)prof, handsets h, handset_inclusions i
WHERE prof.target_profile_id = i.target_profile_id
  AND i.handset_id = h.id)) t
  order by t.target_profile_id;
```

Comment: My question is is there a way to make this explain run faster ? I am using select sub queries and Union them all using distinct selects. Are the select sub-query always very slow in explain plan also ? the same query ran 2-3 min earlier but why is it taking so long now ?

Comment: try to `explain` each subquery separately to find the bottle-neck

Comment: Why don't we see the explain?:)

Answer (score 1):

It was a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44802). MySQL seems to have executed subqueries when running EXPLAIN.

It seems like it should be fixed in MySQL >= 5.6